# Plotting / placing elements onto an SVG image in specific locations

Tags: html, css, dictionary, svg

I'm working on an SVG hexagon map and I'd like to have illustrations I've made placed around the map in specific locations. My idea is for when the user hovers over one, it would play an animation. Would there be any way to go about this whilst still keeping it responsive, i.e. I'd like for these elements to remain in place if I were to resize the window.

For reference, [here's the one I designed in Illustrator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCxKh.png) Bottom layer is the map, top layer with the icons / illustrations.

Cheers!

Comment: Measure everything and then get CSS to work out the percentage top and left values. If you need more help could you put some example code, including the SVG and perhaps a couple of the clickable points, into your question, thanks.

Comment: Please draw in an svg element 2 or 3 hexagons adding the functionality you want. If it doesn't go well show us the code and ask again. Cheers!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp https://www.image-map.net Some tools to help u get going

Comment: What do you mean by "remain in place" - do you want those images absolutely positioned (when the screen is 4000 x 2000 - an image is at 100,100; but when the screen is 1000 x 500, you still want the image at 100, 100? Or do you mean when the screen goes to 1000 x 500, you want the image at 25, 25?

Comment: @MichaelMullany I'd like for these images to remain at the same coordinates, so if the map is resized, the images resize with them, remaining at the same locations if that makes sense?

Comment: If you use a viewBox, this should happen automatically.